# Passing MagicMock return value to testable function

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm beginning to write some unit tests for my company. I want to start by testing the connection to my database. Function `get_database_connection()`- which is defined in a module not specified here- connects to my database. Otherwise, an exception is raised and returns `None`.

```
import pyodbc
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
import package.module
from package.module2 import get_database_connection


@patch("package.module.get_database_connection", MagicMock(return_value=r'Driver=SQL Server;Server=localhost;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;'))
def test_get_database_connection():
    assert get_database_connection() is not None
    assert isinstance(get_database_connection(), pyodbc.Connection)
```

I'm using pytest and unittest frameworks for this project. Though I am new at testing, I was under the impression that the `MagicMock` object found in the `@patch` decorator would pass its return value to `get_database_connection()`. However, running `$ pytest -v -s` returns the error:

```
get_database_connection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parameter1'
```

What am I missing here? Maybe I am misunderstanding how MagicMock and this library works.

*EDIT: For clarification, the first argument I am passing to `@patch` is the location where `get_database_connection()` is used, not where it is defined.

Comment: It looks as if `get_database_connection()` requires an argument, and you are not providing one. Without seeing your `get_database_connection` function we can't really say more than that.

Comment: You are not calling the patched version, but the one imported into your test module - e.g. in this case the location where you _use_ the function is your test module. Of course, it makes no sense to patch a function and than directly call it in the test, as you will just get a mock, but I guess you are doing it to check if the mocking works...